# Why is java saying I haven't initialized variable?

Tags: java

The following code is giving me an error pointing at the 'm' in the statement "return mon;". It states "variable mon might not have been initialized" when it is very clearly initialized at the beginning of this method. it's gotta be something super simple, I just don't understand! Thank you.

```
public String monthName(int month)
{
    String mon;
    switch (month)
    {
        case 1:
            mon = "January";
            break;
        case 2:
            mon = "February";
            break;
        case 3:
            mon = "March";
            break;
        case 4:
            mon = "April";
            break;
        case 5:
            mon = "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            mon = "June";
            break;
        case 7:
            mon = "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            mon = "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            mon = "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            mon = "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            mon = "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            mon = "December";
            break;
    }
    return mon;
}
```

Comment: You need a `default` section of `switch` (or initialize it explicitly).

Comment: You could always just return "January", "February", etc and have a default case to handle it. No need to have a temp variable like that.

Comment: "when it is very clearly initialized at the beginning of this method"...erm care to tell us where?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Who is to say that `month` is always an integer between 1 and 12?  The compiler certainly can't guarantee it.

Either initialize `mon` to null, or set behavior in the `default` case in your `switch`.  (Also, you can just return the month names directly instead of setting them in a temporary variable.)

Alternately, a simpler solution might be

```
String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", ..., "December"};
return monthNames[month - 1];
```

Comment: Default! yeah, I used the temp variable because I had trouble with using the return statement within blocks of statements before (Now that I think it was because of a different, and very simple reason) and just wanted to make sure that it wasn't the problem somehow. Thank you for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0):

You should have a default case for `mon` variable assignment in `switch (month)`. Also you should assign null value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Returning null if the month number is incorrect is only any good if the caller expects that to happen and is prepared to check for null.

If the calling routine is not going to check for a null return, then you should throw a RuntimeException in the default case. This is much better than allowing the code to fail some time later with a null pointer exception caused by a bad month name!

For example..

```
default:
  throw new RuntimeException("Invalid month number "+ month);
```

This will also stop the compiler complaining because there is no way to get to the return statement with mon not initialised.